# Formatting Strings in Python

Tags: python, string, format

I'm printing a title in python and I want it on the center of the screen.
I know I can do it by using

```
"{:^50}".format("Title")
```

But the thing with this command is it only utilizes the width I give in (in this case, 50). But it isn't perfect and is sometimes way off. Even if I approximate the width by observing/guessing, it would go out of format if I re-size the terminal. I always want to align it on the middle of the screen, even when the terminal is re-sized(say, in fullscreen mode). Any ways I can achieve this?

**EDIT:**
I have did this:
    Well, I figured out the way to find the window size,

```
import os
columns = os.popen('stty size', 'r').read().split()[0]
"{:^"+columns+"}".format("Title")
```

but the last line shows error. I finally have the window size, but I cannot format it correctly. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There is no way you can get a formatted string that does that. You can look into the `curses` module, but it's not exactly straightforward.

Comment: The only way for text to move when the window resizes is for you to make it move.  That means either clearing the screen and re-printing it, or using `curses`.

Comment: ouch, so no easy way I guess :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As zondo pointed out, the title won't reposition when the window is resized.

The correct way to do this: `"{:^"+columns+"}".format("Title")` is like so:

```
"{:^{}}".format("Title", width)
#^---------------^ first argument goes with first brace
#   ^--------------------^ second argument goes with second brace and sets the width
```

Comment: This works!! I tried man combinations except that one. Many Thanks!!